# How to stop Visual Studio Code splitting columns of a printed dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, visual-studio-code

The thing is that whenever I print a dataframe with a big amount of columns, visual studio decides to split them in two even tho they dont even fill half of the screen width. How can I stop it from doing this?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: This is not VidualStudio but pandas: `print(df.to_string())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an "issue" of VisualStudio, but rather a feature of pandas.

You can use [`to_string`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_string.html):

```
print(df.to_string())
```

Or increase the `display.width` option:

```
pd.set_option('display.width', 500)
print(df)
```

Example:

```
           col1          col2          col3          col4          col5          col6          col7          col8          col9         col10         col11         col12         col13         col14         col15         col16         col17         col18         col19         col20         col21         col22         col23         col24         col25         col26         col27         col28         col29         col30
0  abcdefghijkl  abcdefghijkl  abcdefghijkl  abcdefghijkl  abcdefghijkl  abcdefghijkl  abcdefghijkl  abcdefghijkl  abcdefghijkl  abcdefghijkl  abcdefghijkl  abcdefghijkl  abcdefghijkl  abcdefghijkl  abcdefghijkl  abcdefghijkl  abcdefghijkl  abcdefghijkl  abcdefghijkl  abcdefghijkl  abcdefghijkl  abcdefghijkl  abcdefghijkl  abcdefghijkl  abcdefghijkl  abcdefghijkl  abcdefghijkl  abcdefghijkl  abcdefghijkl  abcdefghijkl
1   mnopqrstuvw   mnopqrstuvw   mnopqrstuvw   mnopqrstuvw   mnopqrstuvw   mnopqrstuvw   mnopqrstuvw   mnopqrstuvw   mnopqrstuvw   mnopqrstuvw   mnopqrstuvw   mnopqrstuvw   mnopqrstuvw   mnopqrstuvw   mnopqrstuvw   mnopqrstuvw   mnopqrstuvw   mnopqrstuvw   mnopqrstuvw   mnopqrstuvw   mnopqrstuvw   mnopqrstuvw   mnopqrstuvw   mnopqrstuvw   mnopqrstuvw   mnopqrstuvw   mnopqrstuvw   mnopqrstuvw   mnopqrstuvw   mnopqrstuvw
```

Used input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({f'col{i+1}': ['abcdefghijkl', 'mnopqrstuvw']
                   for i in range(20)})
```